# Redirect specific URL's from Firefox to be opened in Chrome

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, redirection

For some odd reason my enterprise meet.google.com doesn't seem to work for me in Firefox browser.

Is there any extension/workaround, that can redirect certain webpages to Chrome?

- Details: Firefox version 67 (settings enabled for trackers, crypto, and resistfingerprinting)
- OS: Windows

Comment: Try to change user agent in Firefox.

Comment: changing user agent didn't help